# iPhone log reader

Tags: iphone, logging, diagnostic

I went to the apple store today to discuss a problem with my iPhone battery, and they plugged it into one of their macs and used an application that interpreted the logs stored on my phone.

So, my question is, does anybody know the name of the application that reads the logs, and if so, where it is available?

Since it is a diagnostic tool, I'm guessing it won't be openly available, but I thought i would ask anyway.

Comment: The application may be called 'Behaviour Scan'. Can anybody tell me where i can find this?

Answer (score 13):

Apple does have some custom applications that allow them to read more information from the phone, however you can use [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/downloads/iPhone_Configuration_Utility_2_0_for_Mac_OS_X) ([Windows version](http://support.apple.com/downloads/iPhone_Configuration_Utility_2_0_for_Windows)) to view the iPhone's console log by plugging in your iPhone/iPod touch and selecting it under the Devices section in the sidebar.

Comment: Excellent find, didn't know anything about that tool.

Comment: Great app, console access is quite interesting.

Comment: There are updated versions of the utility for both [Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1465) and [Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1466).

Answer (score 3):

The app crash logs and baseband logs are synced to your PC/Mac when you sync the phone with iTunes. For example on my PC they can be found and viewed with a text editor by browsing to:

C:\Documents and Settings\andy\Application Data\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\Andys iPhone

Comment: ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice on a Macintosh

Comment: For Vista/Win7: C:\Users\ *username* \AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\ *your iphone name*

Comment: An easy way to get to this folder would be to type `%AppData%` in the address bar in Windows and then navigate to the folder.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's iPhone Configuration utility will let you view the syslog on your iPhone in real time.

Plug in the device, right click on it and select Get Info. Then select Console from the menu on the left.

[Download it from the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12)

Answer (score 2):

There are many log viewers for iOS, just search for "Console log" in the app store.

App names:

1. Consolelog
2. System Console
3. System Log
4. Console

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the developer tools provided by apple, but the Console app will log crashes for your mobile devices as well if you are on a Mac.

Additionally, each crash log item is stored on your computer in *your_user*/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/*your_phone*/

It's likely more of a technical report than something of value, but if you are finding a consistent issue with your app, it's certainly something that the developer would want to see.